# Cannot add more than 32 messages in Azure Queue

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-queues

I try to add 50 messages in an Azure Queue, but seems only the first 32 get queued.

Following [the documentation](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues-20/) I create a queue like this:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount
                      .Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"]);
var queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
var queueName = "queue-" + Guid.NewGuid();
_queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(queueName);
_queue.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Then I add messages to the queue:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var message = new CloudQueueMessage("message" + i);
    _queue.AddMessage(message);
}
```

I open the Queue from Server Explorer-> Windows Azure-> Storeage-> Queues to check what's inside but only the first 32 appear.

I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's seems the problem was with the way that I check for queued messages. If programmatically I check it like this:

```
_queue.FetchAttributes();
Assert.AreEqual(count, _queue.ApproximateMessageCount);
```

then I see that all messages have been successfully added, even for `count > 32`.

However, at Server Explorer window when hitting "View Queue", I guess what happens behind the scenes is a `GetMessages` request which [has a limit of 32](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues-20/#advanced-get).